# How do I get this address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have this:

```
  unsigned int y = (unsigned int)(int*)foo;
```

How do I get the address to where is stored in memory value which `foo` points?

Let's try to explain better, assume that thery are of int type:

```
int x = 10;
int *foo = &x;
unsigned int y = (unsigned int)(int*)foo;
int r = MAGIC(y); /* should be 10 */
x = 13; /* r still should be 10 */
```

`y` should hold x's adddress, it is, address of `10` integer.

`r` should **copy** the value at `y` location, it is, `10` integer.

so any change of `x` (as in `x = 13`) shouldn't change value `r`. This just an int.

The question is: How do I define `MAGIC`?

Comment: No, that's not the question. The question is, why do you want to do this if you already have `foo`? Using an integer to store an address is bound to go wrong some time. I mean, what if you are on a system where addresses are 64 bits and unsigned ints are only 32 bits?

Comment: And that's why `intptr_t` exists.

Comment: In fact, I know about this... as I'm just testing it, I didn't make all code portable. There's `ptrdiff_t` too that I was using before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to use `y` as a pointer when in fact it is defined to the C-compiler as an `unsigned integer`.  Code that was written back in the "bad ol' days" would do stuff like your example.

Code should be more explicit and well defined in its intent, thus:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    main()

    {
    int x = 10;
    int *foo = &x;

    int *y = foo;

        #define MAGIC(A) *A
    int r = MAGIC(y); /* should be 10 */

    x = 13; /* r still should be 10 */

    printf("x=%d, r=%d", x, r);
        // printed (as expected) :: x=13, r=10

     }
```

These days there is NO reason to work around a C-compiler!!

If you are maintaining some old code that does stuff like your original example, then it is probably worth the effort to re-write it using today's programming style.  Note, it can remain written in C, just well-formed C!

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is possible, then

```
#define MAGIC(y) (*((int*)(y)))
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If y is to hold the address of x then it should be declared as:

```
unsigned int *y;
```

MAGIC should simply be the *what is pointed to by* operator.

```
int r = *y;
```

MAGIC is just the asterisk.

Comment: Holding bare address in an "unsigned int" instead of a pointer was the author's intent.

Comment: There is no guarantee that an unsigned int is the same length as a pointer so that is a dangerous intent!

Comment: `intptr_t` is an integer type which is guaranteed to be large enough to store a pointer.